# How to upload the photo to the album using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am making facebook application.Using graph api url ,created an album.It return me album id.I want to upload the image into it.for that I wrote like this https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos?access_token=generated access token&method=post&picture=D:\foldername\Image\file1.png&message=Google but does not post a photo into the album.I getting error. type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#324) Requires upload file".What does it mean?I have already given the file still why it is asking for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Photo Upload into Album on Fan Page failed](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4916731/facebook-photo-upload-into-album-on-fan-page-failed)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when uploading an image when using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)
The issue was resolved after I put a @ infront of the file name. Perhaps it's the same issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to actually use the POST method. It appears that you are using a GET method, with "method=post" in the query string. This can't work, because providing the file patch is not a substitute for providing the file *data*, which a POST request would send.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php sdk to upload a photo: please checkout https://fbphpsdk.herokuapp.com/ for a demo and the code is on github @ https://github.com/eosgood/fbphpsdk/